# React Native Navigator Route Stacks

Tags: react-native

I am building a simple React Native app.

I was originally using `navigator.push()` to go to the next scene but felt like it was not quick enough.

I then decided to create a preset route stacks for each part of my app (i.e. login routes, settings routes, etc). This speed up the transitions really well within the route stacks; however, when I use `immediatelyResetRouteStack` when switching between the route stacks, it goes really slow.

(I also tried to do a really really big stack at the beginning but it took forever for my app to load.)

Is there a better way I should be doing this?

Comment: Are you using Chrome Developer Tools? If you open the menu in react-native apps (F2 or rage shake) and choose dev options, there is option to switch off dev mode along with other options like live reload. Switching dev mode off will significantly improve transitions.